# Databinding and ColorStateList Selector

Tags: android, android-databinding, textcolor, android-selector, android-text-color

I have a recycler view which I need to use one of the color selectors, depending on what value in the data binding, to change the TextView color.

I have two selectors:

color/selector_item_text.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

color/selector_item_textwithspecial.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/pink" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/pink" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/pink" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/orange" />
</selector>
```

And I'm binding it to my TextView like this:

```
<TextView android:text="@{data.displayPrice}"
    android:textColor="@{data.isSpecial ? @color/selector_item_textwithspecial : @color/selector_item_text}"
    style="@style/ProductPrice"/>
```

The problem is that the TextView color is always orange (if it has special) or black. The selection never changes the color. However, if I remove the databinding, it worked as expected.

For example, the following will make TextView becomes pink (when selected) and orange (when not selected)

```
<TextView android:text="@{data.displayPrice}"
    android:textColor="@color/selector_item_textwithspecial"
    style="@style/ProductPrice"/>
```

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Thanks...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, can you remove your styling (style="@style/ProductPrice") and try again. If it does not help can you share your style as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39497037/12838700)

use `android:textColor="@{data.isSpecial ? @colorStateList/selector_item_textwithspecial : @colorStateList/selector_item_text}"`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use ContextCompat to get the colors.

```
<TextView android:text="@{data.displayPrice}"
    android:textColor="@{data.isSpecial ? @{ContextCompat.getColor(context, @color/selector_item_textwithspecial)} : ContextCompat.getColor(context, @color/selector_item_text)}"
    style="@style/ProductPrice"/>
```

while context you need to declare in your root element in your xml file

```
tools:context="...."//path to your activity
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but there is a simple solution given by @Viatcheslav. But I think your solution should work too. +1 for that :)